# Limit supremum properties

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I have the following theorem that I'm trying to prove:

*Let $(s_n)$ be a bounded sequence and let $m = \lim\sup s_n$. Then the following properties hold:*

1. *For every $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists a natural number $N$ such that $n\geq N$ implies that $s_n < m + \varepsilon$.*
2. *For every $\varepsilon > 0$ and for every $i\in\mathbb{N}$ there exists an integer $k > i$ such that $s_k > m-\varepsilon$.*

What I have so far is the following:

> Suppose that for a bounded sequence $(s_n)$, $m = \lim\sup s_n$. Then no number larger than $m$ can be a subsequential limit of $(s_n)$. That is, given any $(s_{n_k})$ and any $\varepsilon > 0$, $\lim_{k\to\infty} s_{n_k} < m+\varepsilon$. Thus there can only be a finite number of terms as large as $m+\varepsilon$, otherwise a subsequence of those terms would have a limit greater than $m$.

The thing I'm struggling with is defining an $N$ such that $n\geq N$ implies $s_n < m + \varepsilon$. Any pointers on how to define such $N$ would be great!

Answer (score 1):

I will define $(a_m^+)_{m=n}^{\infty}$ to be the sequence $(c_m)_{m}^{\infty}$ where $c_k=\text{sup} (a_N)_{N=k}^{\infty}$ (in other words this sequence consists of the suprerum of the sequence $(a_m)_{m=n}^{\infty}$ with the first element of the sequence shifted each time.) The definition of $\limsup s_n$ is then $\inf(s_{N}^+)_{N=m}^{\infty}$.

(1) We always have $m+\epsilon > m ~
\forall \epsilon > 0$, so that $m+\epsilon>\inf (s_N^+)_{N=m}^{\infty}$.

Now if $m+\epsilon < s_k^+ ~ \forall k\geq m$ , then $ m+\epsilon<\inf(s_N^+)$, a contradiction

So $\exists t\geq m$ such that $m+\epsilon > s_t^+$, or $m+\epsilon > \sup (s_t)_{t}^{\infty}$, and by the definition of supremum, we conclude $m+\epsilon > s_n ~\forall n \geq t$.

(2) One always has $m-\epsilon < m ~\forall \epsilon >0$. Thus,

$m-\epsilon<\inf(S_N^+)_{N=m}^{\infty}$ and thus by the definition of infimum,

$m-\epsilon<s_N^+ \forall N\geq m$, fix $N$

Or, $m-\epsilon <\sup (s_m)_{m=N}^{\infty}$.

Now, if $s_k \leq m-\epsilon ~\forall k\geq N$ it would imply $\sup (s_k)_{k=N}^{\infty}=m-\epsilon < \sup (s_m)_{m=N}^{\infty}$, contradiction!

Thus, $\exists j\geq N$ for which $m-\epsilon < s_j$ holds and we are done

Comment: Hello! It is helpful to relate and understand the relationship between $>$ and $\limsup=\inf(\sup (\text{blah blah}))$,for example if one has that $T>\limsup <a_n>$ then it would imply $T>\inf (\sup (\text{something}))$ and the presence of $"sup"$ inside $"inf"$ and use of $>$ tells you that $T>\sup (something)$ and by definition of "sup" it follows this holds for all the elements of the sequence $(a_N)^+$ (indeed this is just for motivation, dont take it rigorously) and the existence of $N$ comes from the "inf" in front, you can make a similar analogy between $<$ and $\liminf$,for motivation